# How to upload an image to Quill rich text editor via quil-image-uploader module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, quill

I have encountered an issue while trying to upload an image to [quil-react](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) via q[uil-image-uploader](https://github.com/NoelOConnell/quill-image-uploader). For some reason if you use the editor with a controlled react component and update the value via onChange function of react-quill, something brakes.

From console.logs I figured that the image gets stuck on base64 representation and then does not reach the next step of being deleted, and re-inserted as an img tag.

Here is a forked version of [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-demo-state-lotd8?file=/src/editor.js)

If you try to upload the image it will not work.

Thanks so much for your help!
If I am totally missing something obvious please point this poor soul towards it, haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing a div inside ReactQuill which is causing problem.
Do it like this:

```
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactQuill
          theme="snow"
          modules={this.modules}
          formats={this.formats}
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={(content) => {
            this.setState({ text: content });
            console.log(content);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Doh, thank you so much Muhammad. Totally did not see that